# Android Studio can't render simple layout

Tags: android, android-studio

Why doesn't this relatively simple layout render in Android Studio?

When I open this file in Android Studio, instead of the rendered preview of the layout, I see "Rendering Problem" and the list of errors shown below.  Yet it looks fine when running on a device.

However, some tweaks to the layout will cause it to be rendered...

- Setting the buttons to a width of 0dp
- Swapping the ordering of LinearLayouts layout_1 and layout_2
- Reducing the height of either layout_1 or layout_2 to 100dp
- Removing the LinearLayouts from the scrollview

This only became an issue when I migrated my project to Gradle and API 21.

---

The layout that will not render in Android Studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/d">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/layout_1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vertical_padding">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout_2"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vertical_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:id="@+id/interface_2"
                android:showDividers="end"
           android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield">

                <!-- Stuff gets inflated into here -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/stats_button_container"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/all_data"
                    android:id="@+id/stats_range_button_1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standard_text_on_white"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/six_months_of_data"
                    android:id="@+id/stats_range_button_2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standard_text_on_white"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/one_month_of_data"
                    android:id="@+id/stats_range_button_3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/standard_text_on_white"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:74)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
>       at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1689)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:587)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:646)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:584)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: Try: File -> Invalidate caches / Restart -> Just restart. And check the "Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE" option (Android icon in the upper navigation bar in Preview mode)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bigdestroyer!
I invalidated the cache and restarted the IDE, but no dice. And the Android version for the IDE layout rendering is set to 21, which is where it should be.  It does render something for versions 19 and 18, though it doesn't look quite right.  Probably the style file for those needs to be updated for the older versions.

Comment: Yes, it cans be. Whhich version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: The latest version as of now, Android Studio 1.1.0

Comment: Have you tried to change Android version for the IDE layout rendering to 19? I had this problem,too and that solved it.

Comment: @Tyson I had this issue as well, in Android Studio 1.1.0 and solved it by switching to version 19